# ListSelect does not single select mode in vaadin 8, what is the replacement?

Tags: vaadin8

We have a vaadin 6 application that has a ListSelect which changes between single select and multiselect mode.  Now we are converting to vaadin 8, the setMultiSelect method is not there any more.  Seems that ListSelect is always multiselect mode in vaadin 8. Is that true? Any method to make ListSelect single selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component you are looking for in Vaadin 8 is probably NativeSelect.

Comment: Thanks for the TIP.  So instead of having one component that can be either single select or multi-select, now need to use NativeSelect for single select and ListSelect for multu-select.  Ok, will try that.